# Python "SystemError: execution of module numpy.random.mtrand failed without setting an exception"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Trying to install einsteinpy and run it in vscode, I'm taking the first example from their [install page](https://docs.einsteinpy.org/en/latest/installation.html) and trying to get it to run, but I'm getting errors which I believe are related to my numpy version being mismatched?

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\theev> & C:/Users/theev/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/theev/Documents/Homework/MPhys/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\theev\Documents\Homework\MPhys\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from einsteinpy.plotting import StaticGeodesicPlotter
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\theev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\einsteinpy\plotting\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from einsteinpy.plotting.fractal import fractal
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\theev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\einsteinpy\plotting\fractal.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\theev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 171, in <module>
    from . import random
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\theev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\theev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SystemError: execution of module numpy.random.mtrand failed without setting an exception
```

I've tried updating all the relevant packages that I'm using (scipy, matplotlib, etc) and also uninstalling and reinstalling numpy, scipy and einsteinpy (using pip). What I'm doing wrong? All I've found online from other questions is people saying it's due to mismatched numpy versions, but I can't find a single solution on how to fix this. i.e. what numpy version should I install? what is it mismatched / clashing with?

Comment: That error doesn't look like it's really related to `einsteinpy`. I would suggest making very sure you've uninstalled all traces of `numpy` before reinstalling it (preferably in a fresh venv).

Comment: I uninstalled it again and made sure to delete a couple of extra numpy files in the python scripts install directory, now numpy is working again cheers! must have just missed those the first time, but einsteinpy still chucks out the same error as before

**Edit:** nevermind, after trying to run einsteinpy once my numpy installation is broken again